# how to hide & show div elements with jquery (not working on second div)

Tags: jquery, html

I have two div's.  I want to show one and hide the other based on a condition.  My problem is that jquery is only assigning the first div, I can tell this by looking at the web developer output to confirm, why?

```
if(!fd.getActiveXInstalled()) {
    $(".divActiveXdownloadButton").hide();
    $(".divActiveXNodownloadButton").show();  
} else {

    $(".divActiveXdownloadButton").show();
    $(".divActiveXNodownloadButton").hide();  
}
```

And markup:

```
<div>
    <div class="divActiveXdownloadButton" style="display:none;">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnDownload" runat="server" ></asp:ImageButton>
    </div>
    <div class="divActiveXNodownloadButton" style="display:none;">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnReturn" runat="server"></asp:ImageButton>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhh Duhhh! I was performing my script before the second div had been rendered! 
I needed some jscript right in the middle of my page to call a third party ActiveX control.  I had mistakenly added my jscript along with that to hide and show controls.
Unfortunately, some of those controls had not been renered yet. I have moved part of the jscript down and now it works.

Thanks to all who provided input.

James

Answer (score 2):

Try hiding the contained elements, I don't know what `<asp:ImageButton>`s turn into, assuming they are input elements of type `image`:

```
if(!fd.getActiveXInstalled()) {
    $('.tdActiveXdownloadButton > input[type=image]').hide();
    $(".tdActiveXdownloadButton > input[type=image]").show();  
} else {    
    $(".tdActiveXdownloadButton > input[type=image]").show();
    $(".tdActiveXdownloadButton > input[type=image]").hide();  
}
```

or maybe just try:

```
$('.tdActiveXdownloadButton').children().hide();
```

or:

```
$('.tdActiveXdownloadButton > *').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't hide table cells at all, they are not intended to be used that way. Either put an element in the cell that you can hide, or don't use a table at all.

Comment: Nope, doesn't like that either.  Will try something else.

Comment: I had tried divs, but centering buttons in the divs was a problem.

Comment: Ok, I changed my td's to divs and I am getting the same results, only the first div is assigned by jquery.... ???

Comment: Ohhh Duhhh!  I think I found it.  I was performing my script before the second div had been rendered!  I have moved it down and am testing that.  My inexperience at work!  Thanks